# Code gives me wrong output after the first time it asks

Tags: python

Why whenever it asks for input I put it in and it gives the right output, but then afterwards it gives the same output no matter what? For example, I type in 5 as my input and then it gives me the right output, but afterwards it asks for input again and when I put an input like say for example 10, it gives me the output for 5 not 10.

```
def menu():


        print()
       # display the menu
        print('Select from the following option:')
        print('\t1) Category')        
        print('\t2) Item')
        print('\t3) Serving Size')
        print('\t4) Calories')
        print('\t5) Calories From Fat')
        print('\t6) Total Fat')
        print('\t7) Cholesterol')
        print('\t8) Sodium')
        print('\t9) Carbohydrate')
        print('\t10) Protein')
        print('\t11) Sugars')
        print('\t12) Quit')
       # Ask the user to a number.
        item = input('Enter Number Command:')
        return item

item = menu()

while item != '12':

        if item == '1':
                print('\t1) Category')
        elif item == '2':

                print('\t2) Item')
        elif item == '3':
                print('\t3) Serving Size')

        #more elif statements I didn't put in so it wouldn't be too much
        else:   
                print('..invalid number...please put valid number')
        item != menu()

menu()
```

It should put the right output even after the first time it asks for input.

Comment: `item = menu()`, not `item != menu()`

Answer (score 2):

You're never changing the value of `item` in line:

`item !=menu()`

You're running `menu()` which is why you're seeing the menu print, but the value of item is never updated. Simply change the inequality to an equal:

```
def menu():


        print()
       # display the menu
        print('Select from the following option:')
        print('\t1) Category')        
        print('\t2) Item')
        print('\t3) Serving Size')
        print('\t4) Calories')
        print('\t5) Calories From Fat')
        print('\t6) Total Fat')
        print('\t7) Cholesterol')
        print('\t8) Sodium')
        print('\t9) Carbohydrate')
        print('\t10) Protein')
        print('\t11) Sugars')
        print('\t12) Quit')
       # Ask the user to a number.
        item = input('Enter Number Command:')
        return item

item = menu()

while item != '12':

        if item == '1':
                print('\t1) Category')
        elif item == '2':

                print('\t2) Item')
        elif item == '3':
                print('\t3) Serving Size')

        #more elif statements I didn't put in so it wouldn't be too much
        else:   
                print('..invalid number...please put valid number')
        item = menu() # item will be updated and assigned a new value

menu()
```